# Prove there is an $a>0$ such that $\forall x\in [0,1]$, $f(x)>x+a$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f(x)>x\space \space \forall x \in [0,1]$. Prove there exists an $a>0$ such that $f(x)>x+a\space \space \forall x \in [0,1]$.

It is really important that I know if I am correct in my attempt:

$Attempt$: Let us look the the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, furthermore $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Since $g$ is continuous on a close interval, it attains, particularly its minimum. Therefore, denoting $c=\min g([0,1])\ne 0$, there exists an $x_1\in [0,1]$ such that $g(x_1)=f(x_1)-x_1=c_1 >0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x_1)=x_1+c_1$. That means for any $x\in [0,1]$, $f(x)=x+s$ $\Rightarrow$ $c_1\le s$. Therefore, for any $x\in [0,1]$, $f(x)\ge x+c_1$. Taking ${1\over 2}c_1\in [0,1]$ we get that for all $x\in [0,1]$, $f(x)>x+{1\over 2}c_1$.

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: $c=\min g([0,1])>0$ , then you can get $f(x)>x+{1\over 2}c$ directly

Comment: Yes but I felt like I had to show it...

Comment: Since $c$ is the minimum of $g$ you have that $g(x)\geq c$ for all $x$. Using the definition of $g$ this implies $f(x)-x\geq c$ for all $x$, or equivalently, $f(x)\geq x+c$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going for a fairly simple approach here. If $f(x) > x \space \space \forall x \in [0, 1]$, then it's also true that $f(x) - x > 0 \space \space \forall x \in [0, 1]$.

Thus, there will always be a number $f(x) - x \space \space \forall x \in [0, 1]$ that is bigger than $0$. This also implies that there exists a number $a$ such that $f(x) - x > a \space \space \forall x \in [0, 1]$ (see picture; note that number $1$ is not marked as it can be any value over $x$). No matter how small $f(x) -x$ is, there will always be a number smaller than that.

The expression can than be re-written to $f(x)> x + a \space \space \forall x \in [0, 1]$, which you wanted to prove.

[image]